# How to handle unique constraint violation correctly in SDN4?

Tags: neo4j, unique-constraint, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I created a Neo4j Extension. It contains my own `TransactionEventHandler`. Sometimes, execution of its `beforeCommit()` method leads to `UniquePropertyConstraintViolationKernelException`. It's okay. But on the server side I receive `ResultProcessingException`. This exception looks too generalized. I think, it may be thrown for many reasons, not only in case of constraint violation. So, my question is how I should to handle constraint violations on the server side? I use SDN4.

**Edit 1: All neo4j-ogm-* versions are updated to 2.0.3**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-http-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're on SDN 4.0, this is a known problem, that the exception thrown is too broad.

In SDN 4.1.1, we introduced a CypherException that wraps the underlying Neo4j error code, and this is thrown uniformly across all 3 drivers when Cypher execution fails. If you're using SDN 4.1.1 and you don't receive this exception, it is possible we've missed some area of the code- please  [raise a github issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues) with details of how to reproduce this.

Update:
Realized that SDN 4.1.1 depends on OGM 2.0.1 which produces a CypherException but does not wrap the cause. Please override neo4j-ogm-core and any drivers versions to 2.0.3
`CypherException.getCode()` should produce `Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintViolation`. Note that if you use the embedded driver, the underlying exception is wrapped. But via the HTTP driver, this information is not received and so you'll receive the following only in the CypherException:

```
code: Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintViolation
description: Node 7 already exists with label User and property "name"=[luanne]
```

Comment: Yes, it's true. After updating of SDN to 4.1.1 I receive CypherException. Description contains a message like this: "TransactionFailureException: Error executing Cypher Transaction.CouldNotCommit". But it's still unclear for me, how I can understand the type of the problem. Inside of the TransactionEventHandler.beforeCommit() I receive `ConstraintViolationException` with clear description. But on the server side I can't see anything about it.

Comment: Thanks! But such configuration causes another problem. I replaced versions of `neo4j-ogm-core` and `neo4j-ogm-http-driver` as you said. And when I try to call `neo4jOperations.query("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Event) ASSERT n.uniqueId IS UNIQUE", Collections.emptyMap());` I receive `NoSuchMethodError` with description like this: "HttpClientBuilder.setSSLContext(SSLContext)". It was working before.

Comment: Please check your dependency tree that all neo4j-ogm-* versions are 2.0.3

Comment: Yes, I sure, all neo4j-ogm-* versions are 2.0.3. Take a look at my updated question.

Comment: Hmm, this was introduced in 2.0.3. The OGM uses version 4.5.2 of httpclient- is there another version around?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114419/discussion-between-victor-dombrovsky-and-luanne).